# Laravel Eloquent truncate - Foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, constraints

I am having some issues with deleting data using Laravel 5. I seem to be stuck on a 'foreign key constraint', while I don't see why.

In my current database model I have a datapoints table, which has a foreign key to the sensors table (datapoints.sensors_id -> sensor.id).

The code I am trying:

```
Route::get('/truncateData', function() {
    DB::table('datapoints')->truncate();
    DB::table('sensors')->truncate();
    return 'Done...';
});
```

The result:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot
> truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
> (`alerting`.`datapoints`, CONSTRAINT `datapoints_sensor_id_foreign`
> FOREIGN KEY (`sensor_id`) REFERENCES `alerting`.`sensors` (`id`))
> (SQL: truncate `sensors`)

I would understand this constraint if the order would be inverse (first deleting sensors), but when datapoints is empty, there should be no problem deleting sensors? I have also tried:

```
DB::table('datapoints')->delete();
DB::table('sensors')->delete();
return 'Done...';
```

Lastly I also tried adding explicitly 'DB::commit()' between the delete statements, but all return the same result.

Is this normal behaviour? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

No, this is the way your database works. You can't truncate table that is referenced by some other table. You may do something like

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
DB::table('datapoints')->truncate();
DB::table('sensors')->truncate();
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

to disable foreign key checks, truncate tables and enable it again.

Comment: Indeed.

I eventually deleted the rows instead of truncating, but this would work also. I was mistaking when I said that the problem also ocurred with deletes.

Comment: This only works with MySQL and derivatives. Use the answer by @JoeGalind for cross compatibility

Comment: Its better Use Eloquent as JoeGalind said, so you can use any database manager, that only works for mysql.

Comment: This is how i solved mine without disabling and enabled foreign key checks [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192207/laravel-5-1-migration-and-seeding-cannot-truncate-a-table-referenced-in-a-foreig/64202344#64202344](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192207/laravel-5-1-migration-and-seeding-cannot-truncate-a-table-referenced-in-a-foreig/64202344#64202344) ... I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 46):

If you prefer to use Eloquent objects, Maksym's answer the "Eloquent" way

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\Models\Datapoint;
use App\Models\Sensor;


Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
Datapoint::truncate();
Sensor::truncate();
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Answer (score 13):

In **Laravel 7 and 8**, for compatibility across 4 databases (**MySql**, **Postgres**, **SQLite** and **SqlServer**) and no Eloquent, you can use:

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
DB::table('datapoints')->truncate();
DB::table('sensors')->truncate();
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue, Am using Laravel 7. But this won't work for me. It throws an error as:  Error 

  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::schema(). How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Zeenath I have edited my answer. This should work.

Comment: Might have to do  \Schema::