# delete all the data in get in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

hi if i have data in laravel like this ..

```
$data = MyModel::get();
```

or maybe my data is an relation one to many like this ..

```
$data->MyModel['get_one_to_many_relation'];
```

how can i delete all data like this ..

```
$data->delete;
```

in normal way i delete like this ..

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
   $d->delete();
   // this will delete them but i have to write the foreach
}
```

so is it possable to delete them without foreach like this ..

```
$data->delete();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete all the rows in a table using Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484404/how-to-delete-all-the-rows-in-a-table-using-eloquent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all your relations using:

```
$data->get_one_to_many_relation()->delete();
```

And then delete your `$data`

```
MyModel::query()->delete();
```